# JS фильтр по поиску городов

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Подскажите, как сделать или где можно прочитать о том, как сделать Фильтр поиска на сайте (фото прикрепляю) + нужна ли база данных городов на MySQL [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за поиск? Что фильтрует/Где уже города применяются?

Comment: поиск для формы HTML

Comment: Для начала, есть HTML-тег `datalist` )

Comment: datalist, для более чем 200 городов ?